# Is it possible to specify a dependency injection container for Visual Studio designer

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, dependency-injection

So that the Visual Studio designer calls the dependency injection container instead of using the default constructor when showing the GUI of a XAML file

Comment: Why the -1 vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, I don't think so, but you should be able to use the [GetIsInDesignMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.designerproperties.getisindesignmode?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077) property to detect whether you're in design mode and set up your dependencies accordingly:

```
public YourView()
{
    ...
    if (DesignerProperties.GetIsInDesignMode(this))
    {
        //set up design time dependencies here...
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what I currently do, but my for design mode only code is pilling up so I am looking for away to reduce that. A designer visible DI container seemed like a possible answer. Basically most of my Views have calls to GetIsInDesignMode.